# How to change position of label in swift

Tags: ios, swift, position, label

i had read a lot how to change position of label but i cant do it.
Here is my simple code

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var TEKST: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var klik: UIButton!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    @IBAction func kliksad(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if (view.backgroundColor==UIColor.green){
            TEKST.isHidden = false
            TEKST.text = "Hi"
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            TEKST.frame.size.width = view.frame.size.width
        } else if(view.backgroundColor == UIColor.red) {
            view.backgroundColor=UIColor.green
            TEKST.textColor=UIColor.purple
            TEKST.text = " Hello "
            TEKST.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 10, y: 50)
            print(TEKST.frame)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does label have any constraints in storyboard? If yes, you need to change them in order to move the label.

Comment: @RomanN should i delete them?

Comment: If you have them, just update constraint's value to move the label:

labelLeftConstraint.constant = 50
view.layoutIfNeeded()

Answer (score 4):

Check for me its working

1) Label with constraints

[image]

[image]

2) My code

```
labelToMove.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 20, y: 20)
```

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

3) result

[image]

Secondly 
this is your Button Action Code

```
if (view.backgroundColor==UIColor.green){
            TEKST.isHidden = false
            TEKST.text = "Hi"
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            TEKST.frame.size.width = view.frame.size.width
        } else if(view.backgroundColor == UIColor.red) {
            view.backgroundColor=UIColor.green
            TEKST.textColor=UIColor.purple
            TEKST.text = " Hello "
            TEKST.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 10, y: 50)
            print(TEKST.frame)
        }
```

You had initialised View.color as green In didLoad
then in action you are checking if color is green make it to red and using else if statement , second statement won't be executed here

```
   @IBAction func MOveLabell(_ sender: Any) {
        if (view.backgroundColor==UIColor.green){
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        } 

        if(view.backgroundColor == UIColor.red) {
            view.backgroundColor=UIColor.red
            labelToMove.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 20, y: 20)
        }

    }
```